# AWS Glue: Command failed with exit code 1

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

My glue job is failing with "Command failed with exit code 1". When I tried to look in the error logs, I find nothing useful ...

When I tried to look into the logs, I see somethings but am not sure if its the cause of error ...

```
19/02/02 02:25:41 INFO ExternalAppendOnlyUnsafeRowArray: Reached spill threshold of 4096 rows, switching to org.apache.spark.util.collection.unsafe.sort.UnsafeExternalSorter
19/02/02 02:25:41 INFO PythonRunner: Times: total = 50, boot = -794, init = 844, finish = 0
19/02/02 02:25:41 INFO PythonRunner: Times: total = 66, boot = -492, init = 558, finish = 0
```

See a bunch of such things ... what does it mean, it does not seem to be the cause? Since it seem to be able to progress beyond this?

```
19/02/02 02:26:46 ERROR CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM
19/02/02 02:26:46 INFO DiskBlockManager: Shutdown hook called
19/02/02 02:26:46 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
19/02/02 02:26:46 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1549073038750_0001/spark-63e4a4fb-d13b-488e-849e-8b9e301d8f12
End of LogType:stderr
```

What does `ERROR CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM` indicate? Perhaps this is the reason why my executors seem to stop giving metrics?

[image]

I note I start of with more executors which seem to stop after a while ...

```
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
19/02/02 02:22:41 INFO GlueCloudwatchSink: CloudwatchSink: Obtained credentials from the Instance Profile
19/02/02 02:22:41 INFO GlueCloudwatchSink: CloudwatchSink: jobName: pinfare-testing jobRunId: jr_a7eb64f80be6184c1c069fdd6914abcb386e0796eed406f230a3cee11341c722
19/02/02 02:22:41 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Connecting to driver: spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@172.31.36.250:46089
19/02/02 02:22:41 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Successfully registered with driver
19/02/02 02:22:41 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID 14 on host ip-172-31-32-233.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal
```

What about this about logging?

I also see things like this: "*Not all bytes were read from the S3ObjectInputStream, aborting HTTP connection. This is likely an error and may result in sub-optimal behavior.*"

```
19/02/02 02:20:35 WARN S3AbortableInputStream: Not all bytes were read from the S3ObjectInputStream, aborting HTTP connection. This is likely an error and may result in sub-optimal behavior. Request only the bytes you need via a ranged GET or drain the input stream after use.
19/02/02 02:20:35 INFO Executor: Finished task 163.0 in stage 8.0 (TID 314). 2853 bytes result sent to driver
19/02/02 02:20:35 INFO FileScanRDD: Reading File path: s3://pinfare-glue/flights/querydestinationplace=9968/querydatetime=2019-01-28/part-00247-fb439e5e-62ba-4afb-8ef9-85aa4d46002f.c000.snappy.parquet, range: 0-22029, partition values: [9968,17924]
19/02/02 02:20:35 INFO S3NativeFileSystem: Opening 's3://pinfare-glue/flights/querydestinationplace=9968/querydatetime=2019-01-28/part-00247-fb439e5e-62ba-4afb-8ef9-85aa4d46002f.c000.snappy.parquet' for reading
19/02/02 02:20:35 WARN S3AbortableInputStream: Not all bytes were read from the S3ObjectInputStream, aborting HTTP connection. This is likely an error and may result in sub-optimal behavior. Request only the bytes you need via a ranged GET or drain the input stream after use.
19/02/02 02:20:35 INFO S3NativeFileSystem: Opening 's3://pinfare-glue/flights/querydestinationplace=9968/querydatetime=2019-01-28/part-00247-fb439e5e-62ba-4afb-8ef9-85aa4d46002f.c000.snappy.parquet' for reading
19/02/02 02:20:35 WARN S3AbortableInputStream: Not all bytes were read from the S3ObjectInputStream, aborting HTTP connection. This is likely an error and may result in sub-optimal behavior. Request only the bytes you need via a ranged GET or drain the input stream after use.
```

My glue job (updated: this appears to be all thats required to crash Glue. It appears Glue cannot read from Data Catalog without running out of memory? The suggestions to fix OOM issues are only for reading S3 files https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-profile-debug-oom-abnormalities.html):

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from pyspark.sql.functions import UserDefinedFunction, regexp_replace, to_timestamp
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, IntegerType, Row

## @params: [JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

# READ IN FLIGHTS, AIRPORTS, AGENTS TABLES
# NOTE: Bookmarks enabled for flights data catalog
airportsGDF = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "pinfare", table_name = "airports")
airportsDF = airportsGDF.toDF().select("airportId", "countryName", "cityName", "airportName")
airportsDF = airportsDF.withColumn("airportId", airportsDF["airportId"].cast("string"))
airportsDF.createOrReplaceTempView("airports")

agentsGDF = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "pinfare", table_name = "agents")
agentsRawDF = agentsGDF.toDF().select("id", "name")
agentsRawDF = agentsRawDF.withColumn("id", agentsRawDF["id"].cast("string"))
agentsRawDF.createOrReplaceTempView("agents")
# agentsRawDF.createOrReplaceTempView("agents_raw")

# agentsDF = spark.sql("""
#     SELECT * FROM agents_raw
#     WHERE type IN ('Airline', 'TravelAgent')
# """) 
# agentsDF.createOrReplaceTempView("agents")

def batch(iterable, n=1):
    l = len(iterable)
    for ndx in range(0, l, n):
        yield iterable[ndx:min(ndx + n, l)]

arr = [13301,12929,14511,9968,15280,10193,13531,13439,16122,9498,16162,17210,12728,14534,12542,13303,16716,13311,12913,11036,17471,16240,10902,15526,17294,15671,10858,17482,12071,12337,17521,12274,10032,17396,11052,9970,12917,12195,10658,17409,13078,17416,17388,12118,10438,13113,11170,14213,9762,10871,11780,12392,15518,13536,10724,14260,16747,18490,17402,10284,10982,10431,16743,12482,10497,15168,16587,15412,17106,11017,17368,13804,15461,19461,16923,9794,12795,25396,12952,15422,10101,14147,10485,12210,25336,9449,15395,13947,11893,11109,9921,9799,15253,16945,13164,10031,17002,17152,16516,13180,16451,16437,11336,13428,10182,25405,16955,10180,12191]

def generate_date_series(start, stop):
    dates = []
    for x in range(0, (stop-start).days + 1):
        date = start + timedelta(days=x)
        dateStr = date.strftime("%Y%m%d")
        print('str', dateStr)
        dateNum = int(dateStr)
        print('num', dateStr)
        dates.append(dateNum)
    return dates
    # return [start + timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, (stop-start).days + 1)]    

spark.udf.register("generate_date_series", generate_date_series, ArrayType(IntegerType()))

# CREATE DF FOR PAST 90 DAYS EXCLUDING PAST 7 DAYS
today = datetime.utcnow().date()
start = today - timedelta(days = 14) # TODO: CHANGE TO 90
sevenDaysAgo = today - timedelta(days = 7)
print(">>> Generate data frame for ", start, " to ", sevenDaysAgo, "... ")
relaventDatesDf = spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(start=start, stop=sevenDaysAgo)
])
relaventDatesDf.createOrReplaceTempView("relaventDates")

relaventDatesDf = spark.sql("SELECT explode(generate_date_series(start, stop)) AS querydatetime FROM relaventDates")
relaventDatesDf.createOrReplaceTempView("relaventDates")

for items in batch(arr, 1):
    batch = ','.join(map(lambda s: str(s), items))

    print("===LOG:START_BATCH_%s===" % (batch))
    flightsGDF = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "pinfare", table_name = "flights", transformation_ctx="flights", push_down_predicate="""
        querydatetime BETWEEN '%s' AND '%s' 
        AND querydestinationplace IN (%s)
    """ % (start.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), batch))

    flightsDf = flightsGDF.toDF()
    flightsDf.createOrReplaceTempView("flights")

    # Attempting to reduce memory usage ... but I dont think this helps at all

    spark.catalog.dropTempView("flights")
    spark.catalog.dropTempView("expandedKeyDates")
    spark.catalog.dropTempView("distinctKeys")

    flightsGDF = None
    flightsDf = None
    resultDf = None
    distinctKeysDf = None
    expandedKeyDatesDf = None
    cleanedFlightsDf = None


job.commit()
```

---

## UPDATE

I tried explaining the query that fails after some iteration, hope this helps:

```
'Project [ArrayBuffer(f).*, 'countryName, 'cityName, 'airportName, 'a.name AS agentName#248, 'CONCAT('f.outboundlegid, -, 'f.inboundlegid, -, 'f.agent) AS key#249]
+- 'Join LeftOuter, ('f.querydestinationplace = 'p.airportId)
:- 'Join LeftOuter, ('f.agent = 'a.id)
: :- 'SubqueryAlias f
: : +- 'UnresolvedRelation `flights`
: +- 'SubqueryAlias a
: +- 'UnresolvedRelation `agents`
+- 'SubqueryAlias p
+- 'UnresolvedRelation `airports`

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
Id: string, QueryTaskId: string, QueryOriginPlace: string, QueryOutboundDate: string, QueryInboundDate: string, QueryCabinClass: string, QueryCurrency: string, Agent: string, QuoteAgeInMinutes: string, Price: string, OutboundLegId: string, InboundLegId: string, OutDeparture: string, OutArrival: string, OutDuration: string, OutJourneyMode: string, OutStops: string, OutCarriers: string, OutOperatingCarriers: string, NumberOutStops: string, NumberOutCarriers: string, NumberOutOperatingCarriers: string, InDeparture: string, InArrival: string, ... 15 more fields
Project [Id#178, QueryTaskId#179, QueryOriginPlace#180, QueryOutboundDate#181, QueryInboundDate#182, QueryCabinClass#183, QueryCurrency#184, Agent#185, QuoteAgeInMinutes#186, Price#187, OutboundLegId#188, InboundLegId#189, OutDeparture#190, OutArrival#191, OutDuration#192, OutJourneyMode#193, OutStops#194, OutCarriers#195, OutOperatingCarriers#196, NumberOutStops#197, NumberOutCarriers#198, NumberOutOperatingCarriers#199, InDeparture#200, InArrival#201, ... 15 more fields]
+- Join LeftOuter, (querydestinationplace#210 = cast(airportId#33 as int))
:- Join LeftOuter, (agent#185 = id#84)
: :- SubqueryAlias f
: : +- SubqueryAlias flights
: : +- LogicalRDD [Id#178, QueryTaskId#179, QueryOriginPlace#180, QueryOutboundDate#181, QueryInboundDate#182, QueryCabinClass#183, QueryCurrency#184, Agent#185, QuoteAgeInMinutes#186, Price#187, OutboundLegId#188, InboundLegId#189, OutDeparture#190, OutArrival#191, OutDuration#192, OutJourneyMode#193, OutStops#194, OutCarriers#195, OutOperatingCarriers#196, NumberOutStops#197, NumberOutCarriers#198, NumberOutOperatingCarriers#199, InDeparture#200, InArrival#201, ... 10 more fields]
: +- SubqueryAlias a
: +- SubqueryAlias agents
: +- Project [cast(id#65L as string) AS id#84, name#66, imageurl#67, status#68, optimisedformobile#69, type#70, bookingnumber#71, createdat#72, updatedat#73]
: +- LogicalRDD [id#65L, name#66, imageurl#67, status#68, optimisedformobile#69, type#70, bookingnumber#71, createdat#72, updatedat#73]
+- SubqueryAlias p
+- SubqueryAlias airports
+- Project [cast(airportId#18L as string) AS airportId#33, cityId#19L, countryId#20L, airportCode#21, airportName#22, cityName#23, countryName#24]
+- LogicalRDD [airportId#18L, cityId#19L, countryId#20L, airportCode#21, airportName#22, cityName#23, countryName#24]

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Project [Id#178, QueryTaskId#179, QueryOriginPlace#180, QueryOutboundDate#181, QueryInboundDate#182, QueryCabinClass#183, QueryCurrency#184, Agent#185, QuoteAgeInMinutes#186, Price#187, OutboundLegId#188, InboundLegId#189, OutDeparture#190, OutArrival#191, OutDuration#192, OutJourneyMode#193, OutStops#194, OutCarriers#195, OutOperatingCarriers#196, NumberOutStops#197, NumberOutCarriers#198, NumberOutOperatingCarriers#199, InDeparture#200, InArrival#201, ... 15 more fields]
+- Join LeftOuter, (querydestinationplace#210 = cast(airportId#33 as int))
:- Project [Id#178, QueryTaskId#179, QueryOriginPlace#180, QueryOutboundDate#181, QueryInboundDate#182, QueryCabinClass#183, QueryCurrency#184, Agent#185, QuoteAgeInMinutes#186, Price#187, OutboundLegId#188, InboundLegId#189, OutDeparture#190, OutArrival#191, OutDuration#192, OutJourneyMode#193, OutStops#194, OutCarriers#195, OutOperatingCarriers#196, NumberOutStops#197, NumberOutCarriers#198, NumberOutOperatingCarriers#199, InDeparture#200, InArrival#201, ... 11 more fields]
: +- Join LeftOuter, (agent#185 = id#84)
: :- LogicalRDD [Id#178, QueryTaskId#179, QueryOriginPlace#180, QueryOutboundDate#181, QueryInboundDate#182, QueryCabinClass#183, QueryCurrency#184, Agent#185, QuoteAgeInMinutes#186, Price#187, OutboundLegId#188, InboundLegId#189, OutDeparture#190, OutArrival#191, OutDuration#192, OutJourneyMode#193, OutStops#194, OutCarriers#195, OutOperatingCarriers#196, NumberOutStops#197, NumberOutCarriers#198, NumberOutOperatingCarriers#199, InDeparture#200, InArrival#201, ... 10 more fields]
: +- Project [cast(id#65L as string) AS id#84, name#66]
: +- LogicalRDD [id#65L, name#66, imageurl#67, status#68, optimisedformobile#69, type#70, bookingnumber#71, createdat#72, updatedat#73]
+- Project [cast(airportId#18L as string) AS airportId#33, airportName#22, cityName#23, countryName#24]
+- LogicalRDD [airportId#18L, cityId#19L, countryId#20L, airportCode#21, airportName#22, cityName#23, countryName#24]

== Physical Plan ==
*Project [Id#178, QueryTaskId#179, QueryOriginPlace#180, QueryOutboundDate#181, QueryInboundDate#182, QueryCabinClass#183, QueryCurrency#184, Agent#185, QuoteAgeInMinutes#186, Price#187, OutboundLegId#188, InboundLegId#189, OutDeparture#190, OutArrival#191, OutDuration#192, OutJourneyMode#193, OutStops#194, OutCarriers#195, OutOperatingCarriers#196, NumberOutStops#197, NumberOutCarriers#198, NumberOutOperatingCarriers#199, InDeparture#200, InArrival#201, ... 15 more fields]
+- SortMergeJoin [querydestinationplace#210], [cast(airportId#33 as int)], LeftOuter
:- *Sort [querydestinationplace#210 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
: +- Exchange hashpartitioning(querydestinationplace#210, 200)
: +- *Project [Id#178, QueryTaskId#179, QueryOriginPlace#180, QueryOutboundDate#181, QueryInboundDate#182, QueryCabinClass#183, QueryCurrency#184, Agent#185, QuoteAgeInMinutes#186, Price#187, OutboundLegId#188, InboundLegId#189, OutDeparture#190, OutArrival#191, OutDuration#192, OutJourneyMode#193, OutStops#194, OutCarriers#195, OutOperatingCarriers#196, NumberOutStops#197, NumberOutCarriers#198, NumberOutOperatingCarriers#199, InDeparture#200, InArrival#201, ... 11 more fields]
: +- SortMergeJoin [agent#185], [id#84], LeftOuter
: :- *Sort [agent#185 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
: : +- Exchange hashpartitioning(agent#185, 200)
: : +- Scan ExistingRDD[Id#178,QueryTaskId#179,QueryOriginPlace#180,QueryOutboundDate#181,QueryInboundDate#182,QueryCabinClass#183,QueryCurrency#184,Agent#185,QuoteAgeInMinutes#186,Price#187,OutboundLegId#188,InboundLegId#189,OutDeparture#190,OutArrival#191,OutDuration#192,OutJourneyMode#193,OutStops#194,OutCarriers#195,OutOperatingCarriers#196,NumberOutStops#197,NumberOutCarriers#198,NumberOutOperatingCarriers#199,InDeparture#200,InArrival#201,... 10 more fields]
: +- *Sort [id#84 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
: +- Exchange hashpartitioning(id#84, 200)
: +- *Project [cast(id#65L as string) AS id#84, name#66]
: +- Scan ExistingRDD[id#65L,name#66,imageurl#67,status#68,optimisedformobile#69,type#70,bookingnumber#71,createdat#72,updatedat#73]
+- *Sort [cast(airportId#33 as int) ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
+- Exchange hashpartitioning(cast(airportId#33 as int), 200)
+- *Project [cast(airportId#18L as string) AS airportId#33, airportName#22, cityName#23, countryName#24]
+- Scan ExistingRDD[airportId#18L,cityId#19L,countryId#20L,airportCode#21,airportName#22,cityName#23,countryName#24]
```